# "good cute girl" vs. "cute good girl": adjective order when they're of the same kind

Tags: adjective-order

for example if I say ***good cute girl*** or ***cute good girl*** does it make any difference?
because both **Cute** and **Good** are **Opinions**.
if both are correct which one is more common and why?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference which order you put those two adjectives in - either way round you won't end up with an idiomatically natural noun phrase, so the example context isn't useful anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although some people don't agree, adjective order in English is often given as: opinion, size, age, shape, colour, origin, material, and purpose. Since 'cute' and 'good' are both opinions, their order does not matter, so you may as well place the one first that you think is most important.

[Adjectives order](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order)

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about the order of adjectives, I would use a more neutral example, such as "this is a beautiful, well-made cake" vs. "this is a well-made, beautiful cake." Either one works, depending on what you are trying to emphasize.

It would be odd for someone to describe a person as either a "cute good girl" or "good cute girl" because the phrase "good girl" (as well as bad girl, good boy, and bad boy) have specific connotations in English that imply a value judgment about the person's moral character. Someone might say that their dog is a "cute, good girl!" but it would be weird to say it about a person.

Comment: How about adding some reference?

Comment: Do you mean for the adjective order, or the meaning of good/bad girl/boy?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that comment directly from `review queue`, I was trying to suggest adding some reference for the adjective order. And I came here again because of the INBOX message. And then I found another answer has given a link. So, just ignore it. Thanks for your contribution and kindness.