# Are "found" and "discovered" interchangeable in context?

Tags: word-usage

In my review queue, I received a nice answer and I suggested adding some reference. A few minutes later the answerer asked what kind of reference needed.

I received that response and redirected to the post. And then I discovered another answer in the post has already provided the reference. So, I [replied](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/242959/109190)

> ... I came here again because of the INBOX message. And then I **found** another answer has given a link. So, just ignore it...

I guess my response is grammatical.

per [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/find), "find" means "to discover where a thing is unexpectedly". It is the situation, I didn't expected there has already been a reference in that post. "Discover" is used in the definition, so I guess I could substitute "discovered" for "found".

> ... I **discovered** another answer has given a link ...

So, "found" and "discovered" are interchangeable in this context, is my understanding? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Discovered** and **found** have the same meaning (only a slight difference).

The difference is:
**Discover** means to find information, a place, or an object, especially for the *first time*.

**Example:** Columbus discovered America (he found America for the first time).

**Find** means to find something or someone *not* for the first time or to encounter or discover something being searched for; to locate.

**Example:**
I had lost my phone, after searching for an hour I found it in my bed.

In your example, you found the answer or link for the first time, so you can say 'discovered'. You could also say *I **came across** the answer that had given a link*.

(By *inbox message*, do you mean 'notification'?)

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you so much. Yes, by inbox message, I mean the  notification next to avatar.

Comment: Good answer but a little deceptively contrastive, it's quite rare that there's only one right answer and even rarer that "found" is wrong.