# Is it idiomatic to say "**nice** answer"?

Tags: idioms

In one of my posts ([Are "found" and "discovered" interchangeable in context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/242983/109190)) I said

> In my review queue, I received a **nice** answer

I guess different people have different standards for good answer. This post is not meant to discuss that standards.

Suppose an answer is clear and helpful, is it idiomatic to refer to that as a "**nice** answer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is entirely idiomatic to refer to a "nice answer", or indeed a "nice" anything, to mean 'good according to the relevant criteria'.  So a nice answer is clear and helpful, a nice cake is tasty, a nice town has low crime and pleasant buildings, a nice dress has attractive fabric and a flattering cut, etc.

In fact, it is *so* commonplace to use "nice" as a generic positive adjective, that it is actively discouraged in some circles (e.g. creative writing courses), in favour of thinking of a more distinctive word.

On the other hand, you appear to be asking if it idiomatic to say a "nice answer**er**".  I am not sure if this is a typo or intentional.  If intentional - no, not really.  I suppose it makes sense grammatically to say "I recieved a reply from a nice answerer", but it's not something I can imagine native speakers saying often, or ever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was a typo. I've corrected it just now.

Comment: It's important to note that in some cases, "nice answer" can imply *unexpectedly* good.  For example, when somebody came up with an answer that was better than the one you were thinking of, or has particularly good qualities that not all good answers would necessarily have.  "Good answer" is fairly factual/neutral in tone, but "nice" often conveys a feeling of the speaker being personally pleased with it as well.